# what should i use instead of ng-repeater

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

i am creating a web app in which i used `ng-repeat` for populating data from database,

here is my code,

```
<select ng-change="getbrandname()" ng-init="ucomname='comname'" ng-model="ucomname">
     <option ng-repeat="o in comnamelistfun" value="comname">{{o.comname}}</option>
 </select>
```

this is my dropdownlist which is populating multiple data from database like
(`com1,com2,com3`)

this is working fine

but what should i use when the data is single and not multiple like in dropdownlist

here is my textbox

```
<td style="width:50%; border:1px solid black; padding:3px; text-align:center;" ng-repeat="c in fullinfo">
   <input type="text" style="margin-left:5%;" value="{{c.AdditionalName}}" ng-model="uaddtionalname" ng-init="uaddtionalname='{{c.AdditionalName}}'" placeholder="Additional Name" Text="" Height="30" />
 </td>
```

this is my textbox i used ng-repeat in my textbox, but i need only one value from the database, what should i use in my textbox instead of ng-repeat

Comment: You can just simply use direct variable, no need to use ng-repeat, just assign one test variable from controller like : $scope.test = "test", and in view you can use it by {{test}}, that's it :)

Comment: sorry sir @JigarPrajapati but i ain't understand

Comment: Let me to give you an answer

Comment: ok sir @JigarPrajapati

Comment: I have posted my answer

Comment: can you please tell me what do you mean by single and multiple. ! show your sample data !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller define one variable like:

```
 $scope.AdditionalName = 'test';
```

Then in your view file :

```
 <td style="width:50%; border:1px solid black; padding:3px; text-align:center;">
       <input type="text" style="margin-left:5%;" value="{{AdditionalName}}" ng-model="AdditionalName" placeholder="Additional Name" Text="" Height="30" />
     </td>
```

As simple as this, it will work, try it.

Comment: but Additionalname is coming from my database

Comment: `updadditionalname: ["TEST"]` i tried this and this works but my data is dynamic not static

Comment: Then you should first initialize and assign you database coming value to this variable , then after you can use it in view directly

Comment: i can see the value in my textbox but my textbox is unable to send the value through ng-model

Comment: @API Controls : I am also talking about dynamic data, not static data :)

Comment: So are you saying that, when form will get submitted or something else, the variable uaddtionalname is not giving you a textbox value ?, it should must give.

Comment: i HAVE UPDATED MY ANSWER, CAN YOU PLEASE TRY NOW?

Comment: sir now my textbox is not binding the data

Comment: @API Controle : I have just guide you that how to use controller variable in view, as i haven't your whole code and the flow that how your data are coming from DB and how you are passing it from controller, you have to just just take guideline from it Man :), i haven't give you a proper working code snippet . :)

Comment: @JigarPrajapati additional name appending